# remove value from array usestate react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to remove a number from an array on click. Basically I've mapped some data into buttons from an array (array is below). Every time you click a button the credit availble value is fed into the `handleAdd` function and from appears at the bottom of the page under `<div>Credit Available</div>`.

Here is a small sample of code, the rest is below.

Attached to an onClick, It checks to see if the `val` is not in the array first to avoid duplicates, if its not in the array, it adds to the array. But if its already in the array when you click it again I want it to be removed. How do I achieve this?

```
  function handleAdd(e, val, id) {
    if (!checkCredit.includes(val)) {
      setCheckCredit([...checkCredit, val]);
    } else if (checkCredit.includes(val)) {
    
    } else {
      console.log("nothing");
    }
  }
```

my button component is here

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../css/Card.scss";

function Card({
  title,
  apr,
  balanceOfferDuration,
  purchaseOfferDuration,
  creditAvailable,
  creditValue,
  onClick,
  selected,
  id
}) {
  return (
    <button
      id={id}
      className={`card__item ${selected ? selected : false}`}
      onClick={onClick}
      readonly
    >
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <p>
        <span> Apr: {apr}</span>
        <span> Balance Transfer Offer Duration: {balanceOfferDuration}</span>
        <span> Purchase Offer Duration: {purchaseOfferDuration}</span>
        <span> Credit Available: £{creditAvailable}</span>
      </p>
    </button>
  );
}

Card.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  apr: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  balanceOfferDuration: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  purchaseOfferDuration: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  creditAvailable: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  creditValue: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  selected: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default Card;
```

The component that maps the buttons and handles the logic:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Card from "./Card";
import {
  studentPayload,
  liquidCardPayload,
  anywhereCardPayload
} from "../data/cardData";

const Cardlist = ({ incomeData, employmentData }) => {
  const [checkCredit, setCheckCredit] = useState([]);
  

  let payloads = [anywhereCardPayload];

  if (employmentData === "student") {
    payloads.push(studentPayload);
  } else if (incomeData >= 15000) {
    payloads.push(liquidCardPayload);
  }

  if (employmentData === "student" && incomeData > 15000) {
    payloads.push(liquidCardPayload);
  }

  function handleAdd(e, val, id) {
    if (!checkCredit.includes(val)) {
      setCheckCredit([...checkCredit, val]);
    } else if (checkCredit.includes(val)) {
    
    } else {
      console.log("nothing");
    }
  }

  console.log(checkCredit);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {payloads.map(detail => (
        <div key={detail.title}>
          <Card
            id={detail.creditAvailable}
            title={detail.title}
            apr={detail.apr}
            onClick={e => handleAdd(e, detail.creditAvailable, detail.id)}
            balanceOfferDuration={detail.balanceOfferDuration}
            purchaseOfferDuration={detail.purchaseOfferDuration}
            creditAvailable={detail.creditAvailable}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      <div>Credit Available: £{checkCredit} </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Cardlist.propTypes = {
  incomeData: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  employmentData: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Cardlist;
```

array values

```
export const studentPayload = {
  id: 1,
  title: "Student Life",
  apr: "18.9",
  balanceOfferDuration: "0 months",
  purchaseOfferDuration: "6 months",
  creditAvailable: 1200,
  selected: false
};

export const liquidCardPayload = {
  id: 2,
  title: "Liquid Card",
  apr: "33.9%",
  balanceOfferDuration: "12 months",
  purchaseOfferDuration: "6 months",
  creditAvailable: 3000,
  selected: false
};

export const anywhereCardPayload = {
  id: 3,
  title: "Anywhere Card",
  apr: "33.9%",
  balanceOfferDuration: "0 months",
  purchaseOfferDuration: "0 months",
  creditAvailable: 300,
  selected: false
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply find the index of the element you're looking for and remove the element with the `splice()` function. Of course, since we're in react it's best practice not to mutate the state/the array but a copy of it:

```
  function handleAdd(e, val, id) {
    if (!checkCredit.includes(val)) {
      setCheckCredit([...checkCredit, val]);
    } else if (checkCredit.includes(val)) {
       const i = checkCredit.indexOf(val);
       if(i > -1) {
         const newCheckCredit = [...checkCredit];
         newCheckCredit.splice(i);
         setCheckCredit(newCheckCredit);
       }
    } else {
      console.log("nothing");
    }
  }
```

Edit: little typo in code